# How to set up an IOTA Sensor for Data Marketplace?

Tags: sensor, development, data-marketplace, raspberry-pi

I own a Raspberry Pi and many sensors. I already had some Sensor projects. How can I set up my own Raspberry Pi sensor to contribute to the data marketplace? Are there any Tutorials yet?

[RuuviLab's Marketplace](https://lab.ruuvi.com/marketplace/)
is what I've found so far. So I see I have to wait for the API. Tell me about new information, please.

Answer (score 10):

The new Data Marketplace API isn't released yet, this is due in December. This will probably just take some JSON sensor data so you might be able to set that up already. I expect that the first version of the new API/SDK will be in Javascript/Node.js, just like for example the Flash channel library.

Comment: https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js

Answer (score -1):

I don´t know if you already found the info yourself but here are two links which could help:

1. Design and implementation of a JavaScript Sensor Framework API by Cao, Thi Thanh Nguyen: https://dspace.cc.tut.fi/dpub/handle/123456789/24588
2. Python implementation by @ikalchev on GitHub: https://github.com/ikalchev/HAP-python

Comment: (Almost) link only answers are discouraged on Stack Exchange. This answer could be improved quite a bit if you can add some explanations as to why those links are helpful and which steps are most important.

Comment: I´will do my best to improve the answer. I work like 16h a day. This is my hobby! Regards, Stefan