# Add a Sensor for the IOTA Data Marketplace

Tags: sensor, data-marketplace

how can i set up my sensors (eg. weather station, etc) to the Data Marketplace. on datum.iota.org are already some. but i can't find a "register" or an "add" button :)

can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

You cant register or buy data at the moment. We have to wait a little longer for the full release.

A similar [question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/157/how-to-set-up-an-iota-sensor-for-data-marketplace?rq=1) has already been asked.

> The new Data Marketplace API isn't released yet, this is due in December. 
>   This will probably just take some JSON sensor data so you might be
>   able to set that up already. I expect that the first version of the
>   new API/SDK will be in Javascript/Node.js, just like for example the
>   Flash channel library.